# Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE") immediately fires the Exited event after launch.. why?

Tags: c#, process, internet-explorer-8

i have a strange problem with IE8 installed in xp. i was trying to launch IE using an System.Diagnostics.Process.Start method in c#. And i have a requirement to trap the exited event of the IE and do some operation. But i ended up in a rather strange problem where the IE immediately fires the exited event after launch.

this is the sample code

```
     Process objProcess = Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE", "http://google.com");

     if (objProcess != null)
    {
        objProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        objProcess.Exited += new EventHandler(myProcess_Exited);        
    }

    public  static void myProcess_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You exited");
    }
```

But the above code perfectly works when laucnching different process (ex:notepad) and it fires the exit event when i close the exe.

this only gives problem launching IE 8. Can someone clarify me what is the problem??

**UPDATE**

Most friends replied my post and saying why you can't  just use an URL? why stick with IE?

**here the reason**

the ultimate aim of the app is to launch an URL from the windows application and will hide an exe when working on the IE. And show the exe after closing the IE.

Thanks

Comment: on my system (XP SP 3, .NET Framework 3.5, IE 8) this code works without any problems. Maybe you have a permission problem?

Comment: did u try with other IE window already opened??

Comment: Note that users with a different default browser won't appreciate that you open IE. You could try just passing the URL to `Process.Start`, but ensure that `UseShellExecute` is set. Of course, this does complicate checking whether the browser exited...

Comment: @Thomas, the aim of the app is to handle the IE exit  . and its going to be an IE only app and running in closed intranet. i ll add some info to my question, hope that clarifies

Comment: Why are you creating IE out of process in the first place?  Why not just create a browser object in process?  Then there's no need to worry about it exiting.

Comment: @Eric, can u pls explain bit more abt waht you are saying..? i cant get you..

Comment: Some objects are always in their own process. You want to talk to excel, you have to start the excel.exe process. Some objects are always in your process. You want to put a button in your app, you don't call cross-process to button.exe; the code for the button runs in your process. *The web browser can be run either way.* Is there some reason why you want to run it out of process instead of in process?

Comment: If i understood correctly, you mean to say why cant use webbrowser object inside winform. Yes we can do that. But the problem is customer wanted to launch the IE out of the running exe process to have real browser exp. its a complex page.

Comment: To more clarification, its an activex ie plugin (the win form) and this would be triggered from my web site in the client machine. And after some client processing in the form, it ll intern trigger the customer specified URL of the legacy system they are using. i hope this clarifies..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Most probably is that you have IE already running as a process, so when you try to launch it again as a new process it looks that there are IE running already, tells it that user initiated a new window (so the initial IE will create a "new" window rather than a new one) and exit.

**Possible solution:**
try starting the process with "-nomerge" command line option:

```
    Process objProcess = Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE", "-nomerge http://google.com/");
```

**Interesting observation**: `objProcess.ExitCode` (for IE8 at least) will be equal to `0` if exited passing control to another instance, and `1` if it was actually closed by user.

Comment: many thanks for the reply Regent. your approach allows me to handle the IE exit on closing. But now the URL is totally messed and displaying something like this "http:///new%20http://google.com/"
and not loading the expected document...

Comment: launching the URL. But not working as expected :(.. this leads to the default behaviour. (firing exited after launch)

Comment: Amazing. Seriously. V. handy. now... what supports -nomerge /nomerge and what doesn't....

Answer (score 3):

If another instance of iexplore.exe is already running on the machine, new instances will connect to that and immediately exit. Also, it's possible that even in the case where iexplore is not running, the [multiprocess architecture](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/03/11/ie8-and-loosely-coupled-ie-lcie.aspx) of Internet Explorer 8 has the parent launch child broker process and exit immediately.

But these answers are besides the point. You should not be launching Internet Explorer directly. If the user has configured another default browser, they will be unhappy that you are ignoring their preferences. Instead, why don't you try

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com");
```

directly and that will do the right thing. You won't be able to tell when the browser closed, but if the command has opened a new tab in an existing browser session for example, the browser close event will be meaningless to your application.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe IEXPLORE itself launches a different process for the URL and ends the process you created? Like a `fork` on Unix?

Comment: Something of this also came to my mind...that iexplore.exe is actually kicking of something else or creating another process for the main program.