# Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "http://google.com") Not Launching On VM. Works on Server and Local

Tags: c#, process.start

As Above in Title

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "http://google.com")
```

Does not launch IE on a VM I am using.  However Executing on a server real machine and local machine it launches correctly.

Tried the following:

```
Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE", "-nomerge http://google.com/");
```

as suggested in post [Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE") immediately fires the Exited event after launch.. why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825105/process-startiexplore-exe-immediately-fires-the-exited-event-after-launch)

and

```
try
 {
     Process.Start("http://google.com");
 }
catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
 {
     Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "http://google.com");
 }
```

and

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you swallowing the `Win32Exception`? What happens if you catch it?

Comment: @Dai This was added as on the real server NOT the Virtual Machine in this case there seem to be an Win32 thrown for `Process.Start("http://google.com")`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan No exceptions seem to occur on the VM the code runs and nothing called, checked task manager for IE incase

Comment: Just to confirm, this code is running within an interactive process, right? (i.e. Console window or WPF/WinForms application)? Creating GUI processes from headless processes like a Windows Service or ASP.NET will fail.

Comment: @Dai yes this code segment is in a C# Console App

Answer (score 0):

You got IE installed on the VM right :D? Anyway try running the app as administrator mayby the UAC settings are "wrong" on the VM.

Comment: Thanks for reading post,  Yes, IE is installed as can just click on icon or go to full path in program files to start I.E. Tried to run as admin unfortunately this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

It will launch the site with your default browser. Assuming that's Internet Explorer, you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stripped down class that you might find useful if you want to do IE automation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using SHDocVw;
using mshtml;

public class InternetExplorerInstance
{
   public InternetExplorer Instance;

   public static InternetExplorerInstance GetCurrentInternetExplorerInstance()
   {
      InternetExplorer currentInternetExplorer = CurrentInternetExplorer();
      if ( currentInternetExplorer != null )
      {
         return new InternetExplorerInstance( currentInternetExplorer );
      }
      return null;
   }

   private InternetExplorerInstance( InternetExplorer ie )
   {
      Instance = ie;
   }

   public static void Iterate()
   {
      GetInternetExplorers();
   }

   private static IEnumerable<InternetExplorer> GetInternetExplorers()
   {
      ShellWindows shellWindows = new ShellWindowsClass();
      List<InternetExplorer> allExplorers = shellWindows.Cast<InternetExplorer>().ToList();
      IEnumerable<InternetExplorer> internetExplorers = allExplorers.Where( ie => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( ie.FullName ).ToLower() == "iexplore" );
      return internetExplorers;
   }

   public static void LaunchNewPage( string url )
   {
      InternetExplorer internetExplorer = GetInternetExplorers().FirstOrDefault();
      if ( internetExplorer != null )
      {
         internetExplorer.Navigate2( url, 0x800 );
         WindowsApi.BringWindowToFront( (IntPtr) internetExplorer.HWND );
      }
      else
      {
         internetExplorer = new InternetExplorer();
         internetExplorer.Visible = true;
         internetExplorer.Navigate2( url );
         WindowsApi.BringWindowToFront((IntPtr) internetExplorer.HWND);
      }

   }
}
```

Not all code is included, but it should be enough for a start.