# C# process start firefox.exe fires the exited immediately after launch

Tags: c#, firefox

Similar to 
[Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE") immediately fires the Exited event after launch.. why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825105/process-startiexplore-exe-immediately-fires-the-exited-event-after-launch)

The -nomerge option does not seem to work for firefox.

Updated:

Here's a preview of the C# code inside a console app

```
static bool exitCalled = false;
static string baseUrl = <some url to display in the browser>;

var process = new Process
{
   StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
   {
      FileName = "Firefox.exe"
      Arguments = " -url " + baseUrl + " -no-remote -P MyProfile "
   }
}

process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Exited += new EventHandler(delegate(Object o, EventArgs e)
{
    // process has exited
    Console.WriteLine("Exited event called");
    Console.ReadLine();
    exitCalled = true;
}

process.Start();
while (!exitCalled)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Running this piece of code displays the "Exited event called" message before the browser is invoked.

Comment: Did you try `/nomerge` rather than `-nomerge`? Obviously it's possible that Firefox doesn't support nomerge, but just wanted to check.

Comment: /nomerge doesn't work either.

Comment: It looks to me like you're calling process.Start _inside_ the object initializer.  Could that be causing a problem?  And instead of that loop, you should use `process.WaitForExit()`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Not sure I understand you point about the object initializer. The 'process' is created before the start is invoked. Also this code works for IE with the -nomerge option. The process.Exited is called when the browser is closed and not before as I am seeing for firefox.

Answer (score 1):

That because `-nomerge` is an IE specific program argument, for firefox you need to use `-no-remote`.  You will also need to pass it the `-P` program argument as well since it is not recommend to start another firefox process with the default profile.  Refer to the following link on starting a new FireFox instance:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_Firefox_with_another_profile

Comment: -no-remote didn't work too. updated my question with sample code. Thanks.

Comment: @BKN I did a little research and what your trying to do will not work without a lot of effort on your part to code around the way firefox works.  Firefox without the -P option will load the default profile which means you can't have 2 instances using default profile.  But you can't use -P with just any profile name because it will show the profile manager once the profile manager exits, the exit event occurs.  From the looks of things it can be done but like I said it will require a fair bit of code.

Comment: Thanks @T.V. My intent is to create a self hosted app using NancyFx/OWIN and allow the user to pick the browser they prefer.